# casting nullable decimal from DataTable

Tags: c#, casting, datatable, nullable

I have a DataTable table. from that table I read value from a column, which is typeof(decimal). I try to cast this value to decimal? dec. When value is null, I get an exception. I tried it this way:

```
decimal? dec= row["myRow"] == null ? null : (decimal?)row["myRow"]; 
//this thorws "Specified cast is not valid." Exception

decimal? dec= myRdr["myValue"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (decimal?)myRdr["myValue"]; 
//this does NOT throw an Exception??
```

I tried the second solution when reading from SQL data table using SQLDataReader and it worked with no problems.

Comment: The second way is the correct way. DbNull and null are not equivalent.

Comment: @dbugger: first one is reading from DataTable, second one is reading from SQL database table. Is a null value in DataTable also DBNull?

Comment: Yes, it will be.  Another syntax would be `if (myRdr["myValue"] is DBNull) ...`.

Comment: Yes. If you feed the table from a database, it will have DbNull values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, `DBNull.Value` and `null` are not same thing. So when you are writing:

```
decimal? dec= row["myRow"] == null ? null : (decimal?)row["myRow"];
```

you are trying doing this:

```
if(DBNull.Value == null)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return (decimal?)row["myRow"];
}
```

which is false so the second part (in else)

```
(decimal?)row["myRow"];
```

is executed. This throws an exception.

But in second case:

```
if(DBNull.Value == DBNull.Value)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return (decimal?)row["myRow"];
}
```

is true so the cast statement is not executed and null is returned.